# Get file contents from file in folder on google cloud storage bucket

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I want to get the contents of a file that resides within a folder in a google storage bucket.

When I try to use the following to get a file in a folder:
// storage.DownloadObject("notification-email-layout/Templates/Email/", "DefaultTemplate.html", stream);

I get an exception: "System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid bucket name 'notification-email-layout/Templates/Email/' "

If I try to hit a file in just the bucket and not in a folder within that bucket it works

--This code works

```
 var storage = StorageClient.Create();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        storage.DownloadObject("notification-email-layout", "test.html", stream);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        sr.BaseStream.Position= 0;
        string txt = "";
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            txt += sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Close();

        return Content(txt, "text/html");
```

How can I get the contents of a file which resides in a folder within a google storage bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the API documentation for [DownloadObject](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_DownloadObject_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Stream_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_DownloadObjectOptions_System_IProgress_Google_Apis_Download_IDownloadProgress__):

```
public virtual Object DownloadObject(
    string bucket,
    string objectName,
    Stream destination,
    DownloadObjectOptions options = null,
    IProgress<IDownloadProgress> progress = null
)
```

The first argument is always the name of the bucket, not a path to an object within a bucket. The second argument is the path to the object.

You probably want to write this instead, if the name of the bucket is "notification-email-layout" and the path to the object is "Templates/Email/test.html":

```
storage.DownloadObject("notification-email-layout", "Templates/Email/test.html", stream);
```

Comment: Duh, yes, that was my issue. Thank you.